# Get a Go file from inside a function by the specified path

Tags: go, import, package

Hi all ) I'm trying to run a code for the specified Database.
The project contains a package "Clients" with sub-packages for the each client(database name). Each sub_package has the "run.go" file with function Run(), which I want to use

-Progect:

-- Clients:

```
---client_1

   ---run.go

---client_2

   ---run.go

---client_3

   ---run.go
```

--main.go

The main file looks like:

```
package main 
 
import ( 
       "flag" 
       "fmt" 
       "os"
   ) 
 
 
func main() { 
   var impl string  
   flag.StringVar(&datbase_name, "database_name", "", "implementation database")

   file_path = fmt.SprintF("./clients/%s", datbase_name)

   file, err := os.Open(file_path)
   if err != nil{                          
        fmt.Println("Unable to open file:", err) 
        os.Exit(1)                         
    }
    defer file.Close()  

    file.Run()
```

but it doesn't work and I understand why (we can read the file only, but not use it)

In Python, we can use internal import (inside a function), but not in Go

So I have no ideas how to pass throw it (

Comment: Go does not support dynamic loading of package source files.  Fix by statically importing the packages into main.  See [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html) for a tutorial on using packages to write a Go program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go doesn't natively allow you to run Go code in Go. While you could use an [interpreter](https://github.com/traefik/yaegi), I would recommend just loading the functions into a map and calling them from there.

```golang
func main() {
   var clients = map[string]func () {
      "client1": client1.Run,
      "client2": client2.Run,
   }

   var database_name string  
   flag.StringVar(&database_name, "database_name", "", "implementation database")

   clients[database_name]()
}
```

You'll have to adjust the `func` for the parameters and returns of the client functions.

Comment: Your welcome :). I just updated it with the correct syntax, I guess I forgot how to write Go.